# Creating Custom Search Webpage Using Google Engine

Tags: search-engine, intranet

I want to create a search webpage which should display the Google results page as well as results from our intranet webpage. Can I design it using Google Custom Search Engine?

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you expose your intranet to the public Internet for Google to index, which is probably not something you want to do.

They have [services to index intranet content](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/gsa.html) as well, but they might be a big costly.

Comment: is it possible for me to get google results using google's custom search engine and intranet search page results using java, and then finally showing the combined results?